# jQuery load only once

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I try to do some jQuery scripts on my rails project. I'm very beginner in both so i have many problems... Right now i dont know how to load jQuery not only once. If i understand, jQuery in rails is loading only once in header - so it works only on first visit? Because when i click for example on logo - that has link_to root_path - jQuery stop working. My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    animation: 'grow'
});
});
```

It works when only on reload. What should i do to make this works after clicking on link_to root_path - its stay on that same page but jQuery stop working.

Comment: If the page doesn't refresh when you click that link, but new data is added, then it's because elements are added dynamically, and the `tooltip` function is not bound to `future elements`. you would need to call `.tooltip()` again after the data is loaded. If you go to a new page entirely and it does not work, then you'll need to check your console for errors.

Comment: no new data is added - its that same page my routes is root :to => "users#index" and when i click on "logo" it link_to root_path, so that same page.

Comment: how can i call again tooltip ?

Comment: [14 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2513971/efectiva?tab=questions&sort=newest)? you have not accepted an answer as correct or helpful in a while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are using turbolink. Some info of [Turbolink on railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=comments).

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        animation: 'grow'
    });
});
```

Comment: nice, now it works, so i must read about turbolinks - thanks.

Comment: Yes :) Have fun with turbolinks